# How to set input shape of a trained model in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am new to TensorFlow and Keras, and I have a trained model that has structure:

```
_________________________________________________________________ 
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
================================================================= 
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________ 
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 8)         216       
_________________________________________________________________
...
```

For some reason (convert model into other CNN framework) I have to fix the batch number from `None` to `1` to make it work, so that the input shape would be: (1,128,128,3). The desired structure would be:

```
_________________________________________________________________ 
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
================================================================= 
input_1 (InputLayer)         (1, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________ 
conv1 (Conv2D)               (1, 64, 64, 8)         216       
_________________________________________________________________ 
...
```

I have tried to replace or insert a new Input layer but it didn't work. Any hint or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new input with an explicit `batch_shape` and pass it to the model. Then create another model.

I don't know whether the other framework will handle this though:

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

newInput = Input(batch_shape=(1,128,128,3))
newOutputs = oldModel(newInput)
newModel = Model(newInput,newOutputs)
```

This creates the model you want on Keras. But the other framework's behavior may be ok or not.

If that doesn't bring you a good result, then you might want to write the entire model again, changing only the input shape:

- if `Sequential`: the first layer should have `batch_input_shape=(1,128,128,3)`
- if `Model`: the input tensor should be as above: `Input(batch_shape=(1,128,128,3))`

After you create t)he new model with the exact same code as the old model, transfer the weights:

```
newModel.set_weights(oldModel.get_weights())
```

Comment: The first solution works, though it gave me a new structure like below: input_1 (1,128,128,3) | model_1(multiple), where in model_1, the InputLayer is still (None,128,128,3)...so I couldn't convert to another framework. I'm going to try rewrite the model again and import the weights. Thanks!